# Vim: how to undo a regex with a new regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I have here a text that has been encrypted in Vi this way:

```
1,$s/\(.\)\1/&&/g
1,$s/\(.\)\(.\)\2\2\2/\2\2\2\1\2/g
1,$s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\3\1\4\2/g
1,$s/\(...\)\(...\)/\2\1/g
```

The task is to write a new regex for each regex in order to undo the changes, so-called decrypting of the text.

I figured out how to undo the last 2 changes:

```
:1,$s/\(...\)\(...\)/\2\1/g
:1,$s/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\2\4\1\3/g
```

I'd like you to explain me what do the first two regex do.
What does \1 or \2\2\2 mean before the forward slash? I assume that after the slash they change places (but wouldn't it be enough to just write \2\1 instead of \2\2\2\1\2(what does it mean?)? I just don't get it). And what does & or && mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following decryption sequence

```
%s/\v(...)(...)/\2\1/g
%s/\v(.)(.)(.)(.)/\2\4\1\3/g
%s/\v(.)\1{2}(.)\1/\2\1\1\1\1/g
%s/\v(.)\1{3}/\1\1/g
```

**Notes :**

1. `1,$` is well written as `%`
2. Use very-magic specifier `\v` to avoid abundant escaping using `\`

---

> What does \1 or \2\2\2 mean before the forward slash?

Since `\1,\2,..` captures what's have been matched within `()`. Hence when they are used in matching pattern itself, they are meant to match repeating characters.

- `(.)`  will match any character but `(.)\1` will match only a charater followed by itself, or in other terms a character repeated 2 times. E.g. in string `abbxyz`, it will match `bb`
- `(.)(.)\2\2\2` will match only a character followed by another character repeating 4 times. It's better written as `(.)(.)\2{3}`. E.g. in string `baabbbbaa`, it will match `abbbb`

---

> And what does & or && mean?

`&` contains a string with entire match. So `&&` is obviously 2 times repetition of matched string.

E.g. input string `abbxyz` and matching pattern is `(.)\1` then it matches `bb` which is stored in `&`. Hence value of `&&` will be `bbbb`

---

**P.S.** I would strongly recommended you to go through [**`The Premier website about Regular Expressions`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) before jumping into such kind of problems.

Comment: how does the \v option work? Will this /\v([2-9])/ be the same as this /\([2-9]\)/?

Comment: @Fizunik No. With `\v` you don't need to escape `()` for capturing. so `/\v([2-9])/` is same as `/\([2-9]\)/`. [Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) are more details

Answer (score 0):

`\1` refers to the first capturing sub-pattern, `\2` the second, etc. `&` is the text that matches the search pattern, so it's the text that matches everything you're searching for (for that specific match, you could have multiple matches in your buffers).

Your first pattern is matching any two characters that repeat. For example, `abb` will be replaced by `abbbb`

Your second pattern matches a character that is followed by another character repeated 4 times (4 consecutive instances of the character in total), and replaces that with the second character three times, then the first character, then the second. For example, `abbbb` will be replaced with `bbbab`

Comment: first regex: `abb` will be replaced by `abbbb` not `abbabb`